# pandas groupby lteration does not work

Tags: python, pandas

I have split my data into training set, validation set, and test set by grouping according to some different groups. The purpose is that the sets will have roughly equal shares of different classes.

After that, I'm trying to scale the data per column in the training set, and use the same transformation for the validation and test set.
Since I iterate over all numeric columns in the training set, I figured I could do the mean imputation by different groups at the same time. Thus, iterating through the numeric columns (features) only once.

Below working code for scaling all features column-wise:

```
for feature_name in numeric_columns:
    tmp_feature_mean = train[feature_name].mean()
    tmp_feature_std = train[feature_name].std()

    train[feature_name].apply(lambda x: (x-tmp_feature_mean)/tmp_feature_std) # !Works
    val[feature_name].apply(lambda x: (x-tmp_feature_mean)/tmp_feature_std) # !Works
    test[feature_name].apply(lambda x: (x-tmp_feature_mean)/tmp_feature_std) # !Works
    train[feature_name] = (train[feature_name]-tmp_feature_mean)/tmp_feature_std # Works
    val[feature_name] = (val[feature_name]-tmp_feature_mean)/tmp_feature_std # Works
    test[feature_name] = (test[feature_name]-tmp_feature_mean)/tmp_feature_std # Works
```

The apply-versions did not seem to do anything.

Now what I would like to do, is replacing NaNs with the mean for that group.
I tried the following:

```
train_Scaled = train.groupby(['class', 'type'])
val_Scaled = val.groupby(['class', 'type'])
test_Scaled = test.groupby(['class', 'type'])

for feature_name in numeric_columns:
    train_feature_mean = train_Scaled[feature_name].mean()
    print "train_feature_mean: {}".format(train_feature_mean)

    train_feature_std = train_Scaled[feature_name].std()
    print "train_feature_std: {}".format(train_feature_std)

    train_Scaled[feature_name] = (train_Scaled[feature_name]-train_feature_mean)/train_feature_std # ValueError
    val_Scaled[feature_name] = (val_Scaled[feature_name]-train_feature_mean)/train_feature_std
    test_Scaled[feature_name] = (test_Scaled[feature_name]-train_feature_mean)/train_feature_std

    for name, group in train_Scaled:    
        train_feature_group_mean = train_Scaled[feature_name].get_group(name).mean()
        print train_feature_group_mean

        train_feature_group_std = train_Scaled[feature_name].get_group(name).std()
        print train_feature_group_std
```

So for each combination of classes and types, I want to fill the NaNs by the mean for that combination. In the above code I have not included the filling at all, since I already run into a problem:

```
train_Scaled[feature_name] = (train_Scaled[feature_name]-train_feature_mean)/train_feature_std# Works
```

Now it fails with the code that in the previous version worked. The difference has probably something to do with the grouping.

I've also tested to first iterate through groups and inside that through features. That way, I tried to fill the NaNs like this:
    train_Scaled[feature_name].get_group(name).fillna(train_group_feature_mean)

But that did not do anything. What's crucial though is to also fill the NaNs with the group mean of the training set in the validation and test sets.

In the end I want training, validation, and tests sets in "normal" pandas dataframes without any grouping. Is this a bad way to get there?
I could just loop through each combination of classes and types to get it done, but I'd prefer if the group by could leverage part of the iteration, since I might want to add other columns to consider for grouping later.

I'm new to both python and pandas, so I'm not surprised if I've gotten something completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it the dirty way, i.e. just looping through features, classes, and types (3 for loops).

I'll post the code as soon as I'm in the cloud again.